# How are indexed columns with NULL values treated?

Tags: informix

Informix-SE 4.10, 7.32 and IDS 11.70: I have an index on a DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION column I recently added as a timestamp to a table with ~800K rows. This column is being populated as users update or add new rows. So far, ~7K rows have DATETIME values, but the rest are NULL. How does SE and IDS treat the rows with NULL valued DATETIME columns when querying, updating and sorting?.. Are those rows ignored? The reason for the index is to support a query to find the most recently added or updated row with a "select max(datetime_col)" statement. Would a descending order index on this column provide better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting for a descending order the `NULLS` will be the last, in the ascending (default) will be in the top.

But the way it is treated depend on the way you filter your data.

You cannot compare `NULL` with a value, it is always false.

Hence, if in that table you try to fetch all rows in which the date is greater than `CURRENT` the rows with the column in `NULL` will not be fetch.

In a similar away if you try to fetch all rows in which the date is lesser than `CURRENT` the rows with the column in `NULL` will not be fetch.

What you want is to test it if it `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: I added the index to support a query which finds the most recently added or updated row, using the timestamped value. Each day, an sql update proc is executed to set the datetime column to null if the current day is not today. Would the query be faster if I add a "where t.timestamp is not null" to the "select max(t.timestamp)" ?

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom: have you looked at the query plans with and without the extra IS NOT NULL clause?  Gut feel is that it won't make much difference, but it might be significant.  One issue will be how often you've run UPDATE STATISTICS for the table.  If the column is nullified overnight and then selectively un-bulled during the day, the statistics might matter.  Have you tried measuring the performance?

Comment: @Jonathan: cost was same in explain. statistics are also updated for that table after the overnight nullification. it appears that all 3 engine versions optimizers are automatically ignoring the rows with null values.

Comment: .. what I'm wondering is whether I'm using the correct method for locating the most recently inserted or updated row, using a datetime col as a timestamp. What if 2 or more users out of the ~500 users happen to commit their transactions at the exact same datetime year to fraction value?

Comment: .. another question I have is whether ~7K rows with NOT NULL datetime values, out of ~800K rows is considered low enough  cardinality to not index the column and let engine scan the table?

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom: While using the `MAX` functions `NULLS` are ignored, unless every value in the column is `NULL`, in that case it returns `NULL`.

If more than one row as a `timestamp` equals to `MAX(timestamp)` then you query will give more than one row.

If you really only want one, and don't mine the above issue, you can `SELECT FIRST 1`.

Comment: As for the question if whether ~7K rows with NOT NULL datetime values, out of ~800K rows is considered low enough cardinality to not index the column and let engine scan the table.

Why are you nullifying the columns? In the explain was it doing a full scan or using the index? 

Has @Jonathan asked, have you tried to measure the performance by doing a full scan and by using the index?

Just to be sure, is your problem in performance or result set?

Keen regards.

Comment: @Ricardo: Ignoring NULL in queries confirmed my suspicion, although I didn't think it would only apply to MAX queries. As to reason for NULLifying previous days transactions, timestamp no longer needed to find most recent insert or update, less rows to evaluate means faster retrieval?.. As to cost without indexing datetime col, scan time was very poor.

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom: I wonder if you'd do better with a separate table, `rows_modified_today` which records the ID number of the row in the current table plus the modification time.  It will only contain the ID numbers of the 0-7K rows that have been modified; it will be small.

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom: If you do UPDATE STATISTICS immediately after the column is nulled, and then don't do it again, the statistics say "everything (in that column) is null".  This might be useful; it might make the queries quicker.  But it isn't strictly accurate after you've done some work.  However, if you're modifying 7K of 800K rows, then the inaccuracy is less than 1%; it may not matter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Separate temp lookup table is a very good idea! I'm assuming you mean the PKID, not ROWID, plus the timestamp of new and updated rows. I had thought of fragmenting on expression the timestamped rows, but row length is 1260 and no fragmentation is availbale for SE. As to updating statistics after nullifying, performance was much pretty much the same, as most of the 7K daily avg. rows are being updated and 200 daily avg rows are inserted.

Comment: .. (continuation)  I'm curious as to how the cost-based C-ISAM and RSAM engines internally handle NULL columns which are or aren't indexed, and if the engines automatically bypass NULL values when querying and sorting, but wonder what would happen if a primary key has null values?  I once heard that when SE went from 2.10 to 4.10, they had optimized indexing algorithms and the way NULLS were dealt with when querying and sorting, but can't find the 4.10 release notes that stated that. I'm sure a lot more optimization has been done since the 4.10 days.

Comment: @FrankComputerAtYmailDotCom: yes, I meant primary key ID, not ROWID. You need a very good reason to store a ROWID in a table; I can't think of one that's good enough. The separate lookup table needn't be a temporary table; it can just be a (permanent) table whose contents are removed regularly. I don't remember now what changed between 2.10 (circa 1986) and 4.10 (circa 1989). However, the optimizer algorithms in SE 5.x and 7.x are essentially the same. The algorithms in SE 4.10 are probably a little less advanced than the current releases, but not by as large a margin as you might hope.

Comment: Eventually, the ~800K rows, with a growth rate of ~200 per day will have their null timestamp column populated as users update them. I added the datetime column in order to determine the most recently inserted or updated row, but wonder if this is a failsafe strategy that guarantees the correct row will be returned. what if two or more users happen to commit exactly at the same time. the datetime column has millisecond precision, and I can't create a unique index on the datetime col as there's more than one row with null values. perhaps I could tap into the transaction log to find it?

Comment: .. to clarify, the timestamp column was a newly added column, therefore all rows initially had NULL value in the timestamp column. Since I only need to know populated timestamp values from the previous work day, I figured the select max(timestamp) from table would run faster if I NULLified timestamps from previous days?